# For each line of input, emit that line alongside output from passing it to a command

Tags: linux, bash

I have an input file with line per value, like the following:

```
100
200
```

I intend to pass each input value to an arbitrary command (here, `abc`), and generate an output file which has both the input and the associated output alongside each other.

Assuming that my command `abc` transforms `100` to `tada` and `200` to `jjhu` (the real production version will do something different), my intended output is:

```
100 tada
200 jjhu
```

Currently, I'm trying to use the following command:

```
cat jobs.txt | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c "echo {}; abc {}"
```

...but its output is:

```
100
tada
200
jjhu
```

How can this be corrected, to put the output on the same line as the input?

Comment: Is there a reason you're considering xargs a priori the appropriate tool for this job?

Comment: I need to execute a given command (eg: abc{} in this q above) on all the integers in jobs.txt. I am new to this and was told xargs was the way to go. Hence.

Comment: ...btw, more information on what the real-world job (as opposed to the `abc` stand-in) is like would be helpful. If it's something genuinely of this form (string concatenation &c), there are approaches that can be used to make it more efficient.

Comment: In your example, `echo` is printing the value with `newline`. You can use `printf` instead. Your example would then be `cat jobs.txt | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c "printf '%s ' {}; abc{}"`.

Comment: @alvits, better to suggest `printf` than `echo -n` -- the latter isn't POSIX-specified to have any particular behavior.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - done. :)

Comment: ...btw, I'm still reading "concatenate two commands" as if you want to run a separate arbitrary *command* and get its output. If the true goal is just to repeat a string twice with a prefix on one instance, then the question should probably be more narrowly written to get answers that don't pay an unnecessary performance cost for unneeded generality..

Comment: It is indeed an arbitrary command @CharlesDuffy

Comment: ...okay, I've tried to edit the question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `xargs` for this task at all. It's inefficient with `-n 1` (running a new and separate shell process for each line of input), and opens you up to security vulnerabilities (consider if your `100` were `$(rm -rf $HOME)` with some escaping to make it act as a single word).

The following can run within a single shell instance, assuming that your input file has one value to each line:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf '%s %s\n' "$line" "$(abc "$line")"
done <jobs.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering the same thing, since it was taking a couple of seconds for the 2 integers itself, when I had >500 integers in jobs.txt it would become a pain. Thanks for suggesting an efficient option.

Comment: Assuming `abc` is an external command, there's still a significant cost to running it -- in an *ideal* world, `abc` would be something where you could feed a single instance multiple inputs, rather than spinning up a copy per line.

Comment: And yes, my input value has one value for each line. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

#### Revised question

For the revised question, you can do one of a couple of things.  One is to use [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42685226/).

Another option is to use `paste` (which was what I suggested in my earliest answer).  Assuming that the command `abc` is benighted enough to only accept a single argument at a time (that's a pain; are you sure you can't get it upgraded to handle multiple arguments in a single invocation?), then you might use:

```
while read -r line
do
    abc "$line"
done < jobs.txt | paste jobs.txt -
```

If the command accepts multiple arguments and generates one line of output per argument, then you could use:

```
xargs abc < jobs.txt | paste jobs.txt -
```

If the command generates multiple lines of output per argument, then you need to fall back on:

```
while read -r line
do echo "$line" $(abc "$line")
done < jobs.txt
```

as the argument processing before `echo` is invoked will flatten the output from `abc` to a single line.  There are carefully and deliberately no quotes around the outside of the `$(…)` here.  If the output contains characters that can screw up shell scripts, you have to work harder — it too is doable (`echo "$line $(abc "$line" | tr '\n' ' ')"`, for instance).

Which of these many options is best depends on details that have not been revealed — any of them could be correct for your task.

#### Previous version of the question

It appeared that the input file was:

```
100
200
```

and the desired output was:

```
100 abc100
200 abc200
```

You can use `sed` to achieve this result with ease:

```
sed 's/.*/& abc&/' jobs.txt
```

Replace the contents of each line read with that line, a space, the letters `abc` and the line again.

Comment: how would I use echo here?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I misread the code — and rewrote the answer while you were commenting.  It wasn't helped by the code not showing the input data, but it was a misread.

Comment: *nod*. This is certainly a responsive answer now, at least to the extent that `abc` is truly representative of the job the OP wants to run, as opposed to a stand-in for "some arbitrary magic happens here".

Comment: @kira: why would you want to use `echo`?  It is counter-productive.  If you must, then perhaps: `while read -r line; do echo "$line abc$line"; done < jobs.txt` would do what you want.  In your code, you should drop the `;` in `sh -c "echo {}; abc{}"` to get the result you want: `sh -c "echo {} abc{}"`.

Comment: Just one additional extension of this - what if my command 'abc' was something like 'a/b/c/'. The forward slashes are breaking the code your answer has above. I am sorry but am completely new to this, hence the q.

Comment: @kira, then you'd use a character other than `/` as your sigil. `sed 's@.*@& abc &@'`

Comment: Never mind, google answered the q. Thanks @JonathanLeffler

Comment: If the replacement string contains `/` characters, use something other than a `/` in the `s///` notation.  For example, `s%.*%& a/b/c/&%` would do the job.  You can even use odd-ball characters like control-A instead of `%`; that seldom runs into conflicts.

Comment: Hey, just one small problem. I think it has to do with how I explained the question. My command does not exactly concatenate but it executes and produces a different output. So, what you are suggesting is only giving me 'abc abc100' as output, but if the command 'abc' did something else than concatenation, then sed does not seem to work.

Comment: Might want `-d $'\n'` on that `xargs abc`, so that if we have a line where the input contains whitespace it remains a single argument. (Granted that this is a GNUism, but xargs is hard to use in ways that are both robust and portable without extensions).

Answer (score 3):

As has been stated, `xargs` is not the right tool for the job:

- [Charles Duffy's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42685226/45375) shows a pure shell solution that is easy to extend, but suitable only for smallish files (shell loops are slow).
  It is the right solution if you need shell functionality for every command, as the OP does, such as when calling *2* commands per input argument.
- If *echoing* values is all you need (which turned out to be *not* the OP's use case, but that wasn't initially obvious), [Jonathan Leffler's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42685258/45375) shows a `sed` command that is a generally faster alternative for larger files.

As for **why your `xargs` command didn't work**:

The only immediate problem was that `echo` terminates its output with a trailing newline, which you can portably work around with `printf`.

Also, `-n 1` is redundant, because it is *overruled* by `-I {}`, which *always* passes *1* argument and uses every input *line as a whole* as an argument, substituting all occurrences (or, per POSIX, up to at least 5) of placeholder `{}` with that one argument.

Finally, it's generally more robust and safer to pass `{}` as a *positional parameter* to the shell (`sh`) and *double-quote* its use in the shell script.
This prevents both unintended modification of the argument and malicious attempts to inject commands.

If we put it all together, we get:

```
xargs -I {} sh -c 'printf "%s " "$1"; abc "$1"' - {} < jobs.txt
```

Note the dummy parameter `-`, which is there because the first argument binds to `$0` inside the shell, not `$1`.

Charles points out that letting the script passed to `sh -c` handle the looping over the input obviates the need for `-I {}` / `-n 1` altogether and also greatly improves performance, because (typically) only a *single* `sh` process is needed.

```
xargs sh -c 'for a; do printf "%s " "$a"; abc "$a"; done' - < jobs.txt
```

<sup>Generally, if the input lines had embedded whitespace and you still wanted to treat each line as a *single* argument, you'd have to use `-d'\n'`, but note that that won't work with BSD/macOS `xargs`.</sup>

Note that this in effect an inline variant of Charles' own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler solution adhering to the OP question would be:

```
cat jobs.txt | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c 'echo -n "{} "; abc {}'
```

As explained alreay in this page, the problem was that the `echo` command outputs a trailing newline, if not instructed to avoid it. The "-n" argument to `echo` does that.

It is said that xargs is not good for this. May be, however it does the job:

File jobs.txt

> 100
>   200

File abc

> echo "a$1/"

```
/tmp$ cat jobs.txt | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c 'echo -n "{} "; ./abc {}'
100 a100/
200 a200/
/tmp$
```

**UPDATE from comment below** (plus other miscellaneous things in this page): this code it's not safe, being prone to data injection. Moreover, the `-n 1` is redundant and, maybe, there can be other issues. So, even if this answer is THE correct reply to the OP question:

> How can this be corrected, to put the output on the same line as the input?

it is strongly adviced to NOT USE this code.

Comment: This code literally has security vulnerabilities. Replace `200` with `$(foo)` in your input file, and you're telling the shell to run `foo` -- a dangerous bug if your data could ever be coming from a process you didn't write yourself. [The approach @mkelement0 suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42685638/14122), using `xargs sh` but passing names as positional arguments rather than substituting them into the generated script, doesn't have this problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ty for pointing it out. I updated the answer. Next time I will analyze every possible security problem.